# How to get all fields from two different tables by foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have a query as part of this function:

```
function user_data($MemberID){ //pass in memberid to get info about user
        $data = array();//data to be returned
        $MemberID =(int)$MemberID;//creating int from this input

        $func_num_args = func_num_args(); //count number of arguments from user data on init.php
        $func_get_args = func_get_args();

        if ($func_num_args >1) { //if more then 1, unset the first element of array 
            unset($func_get_args[0]);

            $fields = '`' . implode('`,`', $func_get_args) . '`';   //taking array and converting to string
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `member`,`oddjob` WHERE `MemberID` = $MemberID"));

                return $data;
```

I call this function (user_data) in the users profile page so that it shows some info about them. However now I also need to be able to display data from another table called `oddjob`.

The `MemberID` is the Primary key in the `member` table. 
`MemberID` is the foreign key in `oddjob` table.
`OddJobID` is the primary key in the `oddjob` table.

I need to edit the query above to pull all fields from both tables based on the MemberID. Ive tried:

```
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `member` INNER JOIN `oddjob` ON `member.MemberID` = `oddjob.MemberID` WHERE `MemberID` = $MemberID"));
```

But keep getting the following error when I log into the users profile page;

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Any help here would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely someone will tell you not to use the mysql functions, but instead use mysqli or pdo.  your query could look like this tho

```
select *
from   member m,
       oddjob o
where  m.MemberID = o.MemberID
and    m.MemberID = $MemberID
```

Comment: thank you very much this works well. yeah I know about mysql and that I should change to mysqli. Plan on doing it at some stage. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

PDO's are the way moving forward, Go for PDO_MYSQL - http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php